# How to Get the exact address location like google map tracker with python/django

Tags: python, django, location, tracker

I've tried to get the location by ip address..but result is wrong..

I'm trying to make a django website..there will be a form field for users current address...and they will just click the location icon...then there current address will set to the value of that field...like google maps...

```
    import requests

    res = requests.get("https://ipinfo.io/")

    data = res.json()
    print(data)
```

I want to know location like this:
[Food panda Location Tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGfF5.png)

[Google location Tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuBqg.png)

Comment: Please provide more information what you are trying to do there and where you tried to retrieve the documentation for your approach.

Comment: I'm trying to make a django website..there will be a form field for users current address...and they will just click the location icon...then there current address will set to the value of that field...like google maps...

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to get the location from the user https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/ , Generally in desktop you can get the location from the IP address.